# Find duplicate entries in an array of strings?

Tags: matlab

I have a large cell array of strings in Matlab. I need to find the indexes of duplicate strings in this array. That is, the output I expect is an array of the indices of strings that appear two or more times in the cell array of strings.

How can I do this?

Comment: Your question is unclear. A MATLAB string is itself a vector...

Comment: @Jubobs Agreed that a MATLAB string is a vector. What I have, however, is a vector of strings, which I suppose that MATLAB represents as a matrix. How is that unclear? What's the ambiguity? Can you be more specific?

Comment: You'd need to show us what that "vector of strings" looks like in your question. Some of the answers below assume that you have a cell array of strings...

Comment: You need to provide more information on your problem, such as expected inputs and outputs.

Comment: @Jubobs Edited. Is it better now?

Comment: @becko That's a bit better, but you could also add a toy example of such a cell array; that would help illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can order the array, and then check for each cell if it equals the following cell.
Runtime = `O(N log(N))`
I don't recall a built-in function for that.

```
Arr = ['aa' 'bb' 'cc' 'bb'];
ArrSort = sort(Arr);// Arr = ['aa' 'bb' 'bb' 'cc']

NewArr = ArrSort(1);
newInd = 1;
for i=2:length(ArrSort)
    if NewArr(newInd) ~= ArrSort(i)
       newInd = newInd + 1;
       NewArr(newInd) = ArrSort(i)
    end
end
```

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Matlab. Can you post the actual code?

Comment: I added the MatLab code. I hope this helps.

Comment: Corrected the code: Matlab uses round parentheses for indexing.

Answer (score 7):

This can be done with [unique](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html):

```
strings = {'some' 'strings' 'with' 'with' 'duplicate' 'strings' 'strings'};
[~, uniqueIdx] =unique(strings) % Find the indices of the unique strings
duplicates = strings % Copy the original into a duplicate array
duplicates(uniqueIdx) = [] % remove the unique strings, anything left is a duplicate
duplicates = unique(duplicates) % find the unique duplicates
```

Comment: This will also work with a non-cell array with the flag `rows` as in `[uniqueStr,uniqueIdx] = unique(strings,'rows');`

Answer (score 2):

Another approach: get integer labels using [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/unique.html), count their ocurrences with [`histc`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/histc.html), and pick those that appear more than once:

```
str = {'hello' 'bye' 'hi' 'farewell' 'hello' 'morning' 'bye' 'bye'}; %// data
[uniqueStr, ~, ind] = unique(str); %// uniqueStr(ind) equals str
repeatedStr = uniqueStr(histc(ind,1:max(ind))>1); %// result
```

Comment: +1. I Like the `histc` approach to retrieve the duplicate indices (the double `unique` from Andy is nice too though)