# MATLAB find uniques not in other list

Tags: matlab, unique, cells

I have a cell array of identifiers, and a cell array of names that corresponds with these identifiers (both string). The identifiers are unique, however the names are not. How can I obtain the unique identifiers that do not have unique names?

ismember and unique alone do not seem to be sufficient

Comment: Please post example input and desired ouput

Comment: IDs = {'number1','number2','number3','number4','number5'}
names = {'first','second','third','first','fifth'}

desired output: 
indices in IDs (or 'number1', 'number4')

Answer (score 1):

Let

```
identifiers = {'a', 'bb', 'ccc', 'eeeee'};
names = {'a', 'bb', 'a', 'dddd', 'ffffff'};
```

To obtain the elements of `identifiers` that appear in `names` *more than once*, or that *never* appear:

```
[ii, jj] = ndgrid(1:numel(names), 1:numel(identifiers)); %// all combinations of indices
matches = sum(strcmp(names(ii), identifiers(jj)), 1); %// sum of matches for each identifier
result_0 = identifiers(matches==0); %// these identifiers never appear
result_1p = identifiers(matches>1); %// these identifiers appear more than once
```

In this example,

```
result_0 = 
    'ccc'    'eeeee'
result_1p = 
    'a'
```

Comment: the thing is, that one list has identifiers, the other names, these are not the same

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you're trying to find the IDs corresponding to non-unique names. Based on Andy's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26347457/find-duplicate-entries-in-an-array-of-strings), we can do the following:

Let's create a cell array `D` containing the names and Ids:

```
IDs = {'number1','number2','number3','number4','number5'}.' 
names = {'first','second','third','first','fifth'} .'

D = [names IDs]
```

The next 4 lines are similar to Andy's solution. The idea is to first find the duplicate entries (here the names), then remove them from the cell array. What is left is the entries that are repeated. You can then easily find the IDs corresponding to them.

Andy's code:

```
[~,uniqueIdx] =unique(D(:,1)) % Find the indices of the unique strings
duplicates = D(:,1) % Copy the original into a duplicate array
duplicates(uniqueIdx) = [] % remove the unique strings, anything left is a duplicate
duplicates = unique(duplicates) % find the unique duplicates
```

And now to find the Ids:

```
NonUniqueRows = strcmp(duplicates,D(:,1))

Out = D(NonUniqueRows,2)
```

Here `Out` is

```
Out = 

    'number1'
    'number4'
```